# Google Chrome App submission permissions

Tags: manifest, chrome-web-store

I want to submit my Web app which is hosted on my own domain to Google Chrome Web store.  I wanted to know if I need to enter anything in the 'permissions' section to allow access to my javascript, iamges and css files (static files) or for hosted sites, you don't need to put anything in the permissions? Thanks.

Here's my manifest (with sample data):

```
{
  "name": "My website name",
  "description": "my website description.",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "version": "1",
  "app": {
    "urls": [
      "*://mywebsite.com/"
    ],
    "launch": {
      "web_url": "http://mywebsite.com/page/"
    }
  },
  "icons": {
    "128": "icon_128.png"
  },
  "permissions": [

  ]
}
```